# php: print out array within form containing empty space

Tags: php, forms

I try to display an array within a form, which works fine, except of the array value containing an empty space 'Street Number', then it only displays the Street.
If I echo it outside of the form it works, but not within the form and the loop:

```
        //This is able to show Street and Number
        echo $Kundendatenarry[4];
        //within the loop and the form it is not working anymore it is only shwoing the street:
        echo"<form name='form1' method='post' action='KundeundAutoBearbeiten_Update.php' accept-charset='UTF-8'>";
        for ($i=1, $max=$Kundendaten->FieldCount(); $i < $max-3; $i++)
            {
                echo"<pre><input size='50' name='name' type='text' id='name' value=".$Kundendatenarry[$i]."></pre><br>";
            }               
        echo"<input type='submit' name='senden' value='Daten Ändern'><br>";
        echo "</form>";
```

I thought "< pre >" could help, but it didn't .

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

These are the db entries:

```
echo $Kundendaten
```

ID,Titel,Vorname,Nachname,Strasse_Hausnummer,Postleitzahl,Stadt,Telefon,EMail,Kommentar,Weihnachtskarte,Erzeugt,Geaendert 11111,,Kurt,Heiz,Rumpenheimerstraße 121, 15625,Offenbach,,,,0,, 
--> It is printed perfektly except of Rumpenheimerstraße 121 --> here it prints out Rumpenheimerstraße  and not the 121

Comment: Is size='50' enough to show the whole streetname + number?

Comment: you want to remove blank entry from your array values???

Comment: you should `htmlentities()` your values incase they contain html tags etc

Comment: If you inspect the resulting html you will notice that the number is there, just not in the value attribute, because the html your loop is generating will be value=street number. You have to do something like: value='".yourarray."'. Edit: in case it is not clear, im wrapping the ".yourarray." in '

Comment: Yes size 50 is enough. I tried htmlentities() but didn't succeed :(

Comment: are you sure theres enough data $i=1 to max-3? try 0 to max

Comment: I have changed it to value='".$Kundendatenarry[$i]."' but it is still cutting of the number :(

Comment: Hi Waygood, yes the data is enough and printed out perfectly except of the one field where I have an empty space inside

Comment: show us the data `in the question` (p.s. htmlentities was not a solution it was a suggestion for programming practice)

Comment: These are the db entries:

Comment: You do realise that you value has no string tags `value=""` so only the first word is valid data

Answer (score 3):

There is no string tags around your input value:

```
echo"<pre><input size='50' name='name' type='text' id='name' value=".$Kundendatenarry[$i]."></pre><br>";
```

should be:

```
echo '<input size="50" name="name" type="text" id="name" value="'.htmlspecialchars($Kundendatenarry[$i]).'"/><br>';
```

I've also added `htmlspecialchars()` too as its common practice to prevent user data breaking the html

Comment: But now it prints out RumpenheimerstraÃ�e 141, instead of Rumpenheimerstraße 141:(

Answer (score 1):

Try using this get result first then echo that result in your html script

```
<?php 
 foreach(condition){
 ?>

<form name='form1' method='post' action='KundeundAutoBearbeiten_Update.php' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<pre><input  name='name' type='text' id='name' value="<?php echo $Kundendatenarry[$i] ?>"></pre><br>
 <input type='submit' name='senden' value='Daten Ändern'><br>
 </form>
<?php 
 }
 //foreach ends
 ?>
```

Strange error, but you can slove using it

Comment: mmmmmh but I need the loop or shall I close php within the loop and then use html?